# How can i output Opportunity Line Items using SOQL query?

Tags: salesforce, soql

If i run this in Salesforce workbench I get one line with three lines under OpportunityLineItems

```
 SELECT Amount, Account.Name, Account.AccountNumber, Name,
(
 SELECT Quantity, UnitPrice, ProductCode,Product2.Name
 FROM OpportunityLineItems
)
FROM Opportunity where Opportunity.Id IN ('07357Jez0204768')
```

The output looks like this
[Workbench query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aEQP.png)

Whereas I want the output to be like the following
[Expected Workbench output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHAyT.png)

How can i get the expected output ? Do i need to change the way the query is written ,
if so how can i do it ?

UPDATE:

```
  {
""attributes"": {
  ""type"": ""Opportunity"",
  ""url"": ""/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/Opportunity/q44l3KquPik6xxxxxxxx""
},
""Amount"": 115.00,
""AccountId"": ""ihdvg2cCRj6Dxxxxxxxx"",
""Name"": ""realtimetest"",
""Id"": ""q44l3KquPik6xxxxxxxx"",
""OpportunityLineItems"": {
  ""totalSize"": 1,
  ""done"": true,
  ""records"": [
    {
      ""attributes"": {
        ""type"": ""OpportunityLineItem"",
        ""url"": ""/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/OpportunityLineItem/IWHHTghK6MA8xxxxxxxx""
      },
      ""OpportunityId"": ""q44l3KquPik6xxxxxxxx"",
      ""Id"": ""IWHHTghK6MA8PzX8HQD9"",
      ""Quantity"": 4.00,
      ""UnitPrice"": 5.00,
      ""ProductCode"": ""product1Code"",
      ""Product2Id"": ""MFqTUKEOHojaxxxxxxxx"",
      ""Product2"": {
        ""attributes"": {
          ""type"": ""Product2"",
          ""url"": ""/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/Product2/MFqTUKEOHojaxxxxxxxx""
        },
        ""Id"": ""MFqTUKEOHojaxxxxxxxx"",
        ""Name"": ""product1Name""
      }
    }              
  ]
},
""Account"": {
  ""attributes"": {
    ""type"": ""Account"",
    ""url"": ""/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/Account/ihdvg2cCRj6Dxxxxxxxx""
  },
  ""Id"": ""ihdvg2cCRj6Dxxxxxxxx"",
  ""Name"": ""My Test Opp""
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your query is written "top-down", looks similar to Salesforce UI with header and related lists. It behaves a bit like that:

```soql
    SELECT Id, Name,
       (SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName FROM Opportunities),
       (SELECT Id, Email FROM Contacts),
       (SELECT Id, Subject FROM Tasks)
    FROM Account
```

It's more useful when you want to see header + line items (Orders? Case Comments?) in one go. Nicely grouped together even if you'd see 10 opportunities.

Sounds like you'd prefer a "bottom-up" where we start from Opportunity Line Item. And that's OK - but for different applications. With that form it's bit trickier to detect boundaries if you see lines that belong to 10 opps - you'd need to order them etc.

```soql
SELECT Opportunity.Amount, Name, Opportunity.Account.Name,
Opportunity.Account.AccountNumber, Quantity, UnitPrice, ProductCode, Product2.Name
FROM OpportunityLineItem
```

Comment: I have this query on a SF trigger so that if i edit the description of an Opportunity then the query will run . So i have created a query on the edit of an opportunity , not the opportunityLineItem

Comment: Think about bulk operations. Directly querying line items is simpler to understand but think what if in future you mass edit the descriptions and need to attribute them down to line items. Whatever you do, copy the description down or kinda rebuild it from line items - the "top-down" form has stuff nicely grouped together, saving you the trouble of working with hand-crafted mess like Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>?

Comment: So in other words it is better to directly querying the items ? Is there no way i can for now re-craft the query to give the desired outcome ? As my trigger is on an edit of opportunity description not opportunitylineitem ?

Comment: Both queries will work, both need opportunity id. Workbench displays them different, true - but for both you can use apex to access the results, fields similar way. Maybe post more code and what exactly you're trying to do with line items. I'm trying to say that what you had originally may look unnatural but (depending on what you're doing with them) can make developer's job much easier later on

Comment: I have a Json result set that has a parent and child records. Is there a standard way in c# i can traverse this SF json result set  to create a datatable ?

Comment: If required i can update the question to include a sample of the json

Comment: I have updated the question to include the json, thanks

Comment: I'm not a C# person, sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17842600/313628 looks promising? And then if your original query - `stuff.OpportunityLineItems.records` should work. If my query - just `stuff.records` I think